# If value is Selected yes, Then I need to show 3rd dropdown otherwise 3rd dropdown should hide

Tags: angular, angular-material

I Have Three dropdown Fields, If you click,you will get two Options. 
For 2nd DropDown, If I select option YES, I need to hide the 3rd dropdown.
How can I do that in Angular-Material, If I use ngModel on "mat-select" Its not working
Can anyone help me in this??
Thanks in Advance..

```
<div class="space">
<mat-form-field>
  <mat-label>Is this partner a PEP?</mat-label>
  <mat-select disableRipple>
    <mat-option value=""></mat-option>
    <mat-option value="1">Yes</mat-option>
    <mat-option value="2">No</mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>

<mat-form-field>
  <mat-label>Does this partner blacklisted</mat-label>
  <mat-select disableRipple >
    <mat-option value=""></mat-option>
    <mat-option value="1">Yes</mat-option>
    <mat-option value="2">No</mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>

<mat-form-field>
  <mat-label>Blacklist Name(s)</mat-label>
  <mat-select>
   </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use `value` and not `ngModel` like this:

**HTML:**

```
<mat-form-field>
  <mat-label>Is this partner a PEP?</mat-label>
  <mat-select disableRipple>
    <mat-option value="1">Yes</mat-option>
    <mat-option value="2">No</mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
<mat-form-field>
  <mat-label>Does this partner blacklisted</mat-label>
  <mat-select disableRipple [(value)]="selected">
    <mat-option value="1">Yes</mat-option>
    <mat-option value="2">No</mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
<mat-form-field *ngIf="selected == 1">
  <mat-label>Blacklist Name(s)</mat-label>
  <mat-select>
   </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

**TS:**

```
export class SelectValueBindingExample {
  selected = '1';
}
```

[image]

[**StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackoverflow-if-value-is-selected-3rd-dropdown-is-show)

Comment: Thanks for your response.. It was exactly I want... But I need that for 2nd Dropdown and If I select Yes, Then 3rd dropdown should hide...Can you please change the above code for my requirement ....Thanks in Advance

Comment: Its Working Fine.. But how can I represent them in a single Row??

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Template Reference variable` for it like

```
  <mat-select disableRipple #second>
    <mat-option value=""></mat-option>
    <mat-option value="1">Yes</mat-option>
    <mat-option value="2">No</mat-option>
  </mat-select>
  <mat-select *ngIf="second.value != 1">
     <mat-option value=""></mat-option>
   </mat-select>
```

[STACKBLITZ](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackoverflow-if-value-is-selected-3rd-dropdown-is-show-7zm4bg)

Comment: ...Thanks for your Response...But is not taking dropdown value "Yes" if I select Yes

Comment: @sundeep: are you sure you have used #second template variable on second dropdown because it's perfectly work at my end